# How to count Parse API requests over a period of time in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, query-performance

I am currently developing an iOS app that leverages Parse and its SDK. We would like to get a rough idea of the average number of API requests our app is firing over a time period when out testers are using it. This is important for us, as Parse has a hard limit of 30 req/s her billing cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information via Parse.com instead of spending time trying to create your own counter and aggregating the data.  Go to your app in Parse, tap Analytics in the top bar and then performance in the left pane.  You will be able to see the server requests over a period of time and be able to see if you are close to the limit or not.